# React Native independent (tab/drawer) navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation

I am still trying to figure out how to create independent tab bar and drawer Navigation in React Native.

The drawer navigation should display for example

- Screen01
- Screen02
- Screen03
- Screen04
- Screen05

whereas the tab bar navigation should only display

- Screen01
- Screen03
- Screen05.

I already have a drawer/tab bar navigation combination working, but I was not able to make it work independent yet. Every screen is visible for both navigation types.

If you want to see the code, let me know :) Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
This is my code using Erik's answer.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import HomeScreen from './Components/Screens/HomeScreen'
import SearchScreen from './Components/Screens/SearchScreen'
import FavoritesScreen from './Components/Screens/FavoritesScreen'
import ProfileScreen from './Components/Screens/ProfileScreen'
import FAQScreen from './Components/Screens/FAQScreen'
import SettingsScreen from './Components/Screens/SettingsScreen'


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const container = createAppContainer(Stack)

function TabScreens() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Favorites" component={FavoritesScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function DrawerScreens() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="FAQ" component={FAQScreen} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={TabScreens} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Drawer" component={DrawerScreens} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: take a look at my earlier answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65199120/how-to-create-a-drawer-using-react-native?noredirect=1#comment115321195_65199120

Comment: @ErikDreifaldt Can you please have a look at the edited question. I've tried to use your answer as a help, but it didn't work out as planned.

Comment: Have you installed packages and imported the packages? 
Take a look here: https://www.reactnativeschool.com/master-react-navigation-v5/
Great tutorial for getting started with react-navigation 5.